# What is the difference between Organizational Unit and posixGroup in LDAP?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I want to organize my organization with the LDAP protocol.
What is the difference between Organizational Unit and posixGroup?

Comment: OUs are usually used as container entries and have sub-entries. Groups are entries that have *members* linked via attributes and `posixGroup` represents POSIX user group (UNIX group entry). So I would guess you don't want to use posixGroup :) (note that there are usually also groupOfNames and groupOfUniqueNames objectclasses... but you probably want organizational units).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Organizational Units (OU's) are used to define a hierarchical tree structure to organize entries in a directory (users, computers, groups, etc.). Like [Pavel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657903/what-is-the-difference-between-organizational-unit-and-posixgroup-in-ldap#comment90279790_51657903) said, posixGroup is an object class for entries that represent a UNIX group.

You'll want to use OU's to organize your LDAP entries. For example:

```
+ OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com
    - CN=Jane Doe,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com
    - CN=John Smith,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com
+ OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=com
    + OU=DistributionLists,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=com
        - CN=DL_ITNews,OU=DistributionLists,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=com
    + OU=PosixGroups,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=com
        - CN=GlobalAdmins,OU=PosixGroups,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=com
        - CN=LocalSudoers,OU=PosixGroups,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=com
+ OU=Computers,DC=example,DC=com
    + OU=Laptops,OU=Computers,DC=example,DC=com
        - CN=LaptopA,OU=Laptops,OU=Computers,DC=example,DC=com
        - CN=LaptopB,OU=Laptops,OU=Computers,DC=example,DC=com
    + OU=Desktops,OU=Computers,DC=example,DC=com
        - CN=DesktopA,OU=Desktops,OU=Computers,DC=example,DC=com
        - CN=DesktopB,OU=Desktops,OU=Computers,DC=example,DC=com
```

This gives us a logical way of maintaining many different types of LDAP entries, and OU's can be "extended" to imply more distinction between similar entries. Here we have two posixGroup entries that have been organized into their own OU `PosixGroups` that belongs to the parent OU `Groups`. These groups may have attributes that describe the group or define membership (e.g. Jane Doe may be in the `GlobalAdmins` group that grants root access to all devices in the `Computers` OU), but how the posixGroups are used and what rules apply to them are defined by the SysAdmins and the applications that use them. The posixGroups themselves do not supply any inherent organizational structure, unlike OU's.